# Вывод структуры

Tags: c++, структуры

Не могу сделать вывод на консоль, если игрок играет:
больше 10 лет - "уже ветеран";
меньше 3 - "новичек";
в остальном случаи - "уже не новичек".

```
struct car {
    string FIO;
    string Comanda;
    int number;
    int year;
};

    int main()
{

    cout << "Введите количество игроков: ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cin.get();
    car* p_car = new car[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Футболист №" << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
        cout << "ФИО игрока: " << endl;
        cin >> p_car[i].FIO;

        cout << "Команда: " << endl;
        cin >> p_car[i].Comanda;

        cout << "Номер игрока: " << endl;
        cin >> p_car[i].number;

        cout << "Год, с которого начал играть: " << endl;
        cin >> p_car[i].year;
        cin.get();
    }
    cout << "\nРезультат:" << endl;
    const int YEAR = 2021;


    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (p_car->year < YEAR && p_car->year>=2019) {
            cout << p_car[i].FIO << " - " << p_car[i].Comanda << " - " << p_car[i].number << " - " << p_car[i].year << "и он новичок" << '\n';

        }
        else if (p_car->year < YEAR && p_car->year>=2011)
        {
            cout << p_car[i].FIO << " - " << p_car[i].Comanda << " - " << p_car[i].number << " - " << p_car[i].year << "и уже ветеран!" << '\n';
        }
        else {
            cout << p_car[i].FIO << " - " << p_car[i].Comanda << " - " << p_car[i].number << " - " << p_car[i].year << "и он уже не новичок" << '\n';
        }
    
    }
    delete[] p_car;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваши проверки `p_car->year` относятся только к первому игроку. Т.е. вы вывод делаете для разных игроков, а проверку - каждый раз для одного и того же.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
struct car 
{
    string FIO;
    string Comanda;
    int number;
    int year;
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Введите количество игроков: ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    car** p_car = new car*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        p_car[i] = new car;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Футболист №" << i + 1 << ":" << endl;
        cout << "ФИО игрока: " << endl;
        cin >> p_car[i]->FIO;

        cout << "Команда: " << endl;
        cin >> p_car[i]->Comanda;

        cout << "Номер игрока: " << endl;
        cin >> p_car[i]->number;

        cout << "Год, с которого начал играть: " << endl;
        cin >> p_car[i]->year;
    }
    cout << "\nРезультат:" << endl;
    const int YEAR = 2021;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << p_car[i]->FIO << " - " << p_car[i]->Comanda << " - " << p_car[i]->number << " - " << p_car[i]->year<<" - ";
        int sr = abs(p_car[i]->year - YEAR);
        if(sr>10)
        {
            cout << " Experienced man";
        }
        if (sr < 3)
        {
            cout << "Beginner";
        }
        if (sr >= 3 && sr <= 10)
        {
            cout << "Intermediate";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    //delete[] p_car;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: показал в основном место где проверка идет на возраст. удаление памяти мной неверно реализовано